# Eigen Vectors and Eigen Values for an indicator random variable matrix

Tags: matrices, random-variables, random-matrices

I have an initial matrix X. We can assume each element to be gaussian random variable around some mean, this mean being different for each element. I use an indicator random variable matrix Y, such that $Y = \textbf{1}(X \ge 0)$, i.e. Y is a matrix made up of Random Variables.

Now I want to decompose it into eigen vector ($V$) and eigen value($\Lambda$) matrix. Does $V$ and/or $\Lambda$ follow any specific distribution? Or can I find the Expectation of $V$ and $\Lambda$ individually?

Context: I have many such Y's, and I take the mean of them and get an expression for E(Y), and equate the two (using law of large numbers). Now I want to do the same, but with $V$ and $\Lambda$ instead of $Y$.

**Edit**: Added context.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @mic, thanks for the reply. I have added the context now.